# open a folder from application by default file manager

Tags: java, android

I want to open a folder base on the path by device file manager .
I create a folder and save in save it into SharedPreferences . 
now I want to open this folder .

I create a folder like this :

```
public static File myDirectory;


myDirectory  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getString(R.string.app_name));
    if(!myDirectory.exists()) {
        myDirectory.mkdirs();
    }
```

in my application class.

and now I want to open this address:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            +  File.separator + getString(R.string.app_name) + File.separator);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

how can I open it by default file manager ?

Comment: There is no standard `Intent` action in Android for viewing a directory, sorry.

Comment: it means that it is impossible ?

Comment: It means that there will not be a reliable solution. There are 26,000+ device models, with hundreds of different built-in file managers, plus hundreds of additional file managers available in the Play Store and elsewhere. None have to support opening a directory. None have to support a common `Intent` structure for opening a directory. You might find some undocumented `Intent` structures that work with a few of the file managers, but do not assume that it will work with all of them.